# Kivy v1.11.1 nested box layout

Tags: python, nested, kivy

I created a nesteded box layout with Kivy, which works. But I need to call three classes in my Python code. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? E.g. with just having one class in Python?

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class HorizLayout1(BoxLayout):
    pass
class HorizLayout2(BoxLayout):
    pass

class VertLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class KivyTestsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VertLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyTestsApp().run()
```

kivytests.kv:

```
<HorizLayout1>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Button:
        text: "1"
    Button:
        text: "2"

<HorizLayout2>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Button:
        text: "3"
    Button:
        text: "4"

<VertLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    HorizLayout1:
    HorizLayout2:
```

Comment: Why you need to call it and where do you do it? You don't need to create different class of every widget you use, especially when you use it just once.

Answer (score 0):

Your `py` could be this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class VertLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class KivyTestsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VertLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyTestsApp().run()
```

... and your `kv` could be this:

```py
<VertLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "1"
        Button:
            text: "2"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "3"
        Button:
            text: "4"
```